# If $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$, prove that the least square estimator $\hat\beta$ is independent of $Y-X\hat{\beta}$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, normal-distribution, linear-regression

Let $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$, where $Y$ is an $n$ by $1$ vector, $X$ is an $n$ by $p$ matrix with full rank and $\epsilon$ is an $n$ by 1 vector of random errors independently and normally distribution with mean vector $0$ and variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma=\sigma^2 I$, with $0$ being an $n$ by $1$ vector of zeros and $I$ being the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix. Prove the least square estimator $\hat{\beta}$ and $Y-X\hat{\beta}$ are independent vectors.

I already get $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^{T}Y$. But I tried to prove independence, but I cannot.

Comment: Hint: show that $\hat{\beta}$ and $Y-X\hat{\beta}$ are _jointly normal_ random vectors. Since the two are _uncorrelated_, they must also be independent.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to prove $E(\hat{\beta} (Y-X\hat{\beta})^T)=0$. I substitute $\hat{\beta}$, and get $E[(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} Y Y^{T}-(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T}Y Y^{T}X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}]$. But I do not how to proceed.

Comment: I also get $E(\hat{\beta}(Y-X\hat{\beta})^{T})=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}E(Y Y^{T})-(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}E(Y Y^{T})(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$.

Comment: The term "independence" is ambiguous as it is used for "statistical independence" but has another meaning in linear algebra. What do you mean here? Note that the vectors $\beta$ and $Y-X\beta$ do not have the same dimension.

Comment: @DilipSarwate To show that $\hat{y}$ and $Y - X \hat{\beta}$ are jointly normal, wouldn't you have to actually know they're independent?

Comment: @student010101Jointly normal random variables need not be independent. Any multivariate normal distribution is by definition jointly normal (i.e. any linear combination is univariate normal), but as long as their covariance is not $0$, they are not independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $\hat\beta:=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ as the vector of estimated parameters and $r:=Y-X\hat\beta$ the vector of residuals, introduce the *hat matrix*
$
H:=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$. Check that $X\hat\beta=HY$ and $X=HX$, so
$$r:=Y-X\hat\beta=Y-HY=(I-H)Y=(I-H)(X\beta +\epsilon)=(I-H)\epsilon.\tag1
$$
In particular $E( r)=(I-H)E(\epsilon)=0$, so to show $r$ and $\hat\beta$ are uncorrelated it's enough to show $E(r\hat\beta^T)=0$. Indeed:
$$
\begin{align}
E(r\hat\beta^T)&=E\left(\left[(I-H)\epsilon\right]\left[(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY\right]^T\right)\\
&\stackrel{(a)}=E\left((I-H)\epsilon Y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}\right)\\
&\stackrel{(b)}=(I-H)E(\epsilon Y^T) X(X^TX)^{-1}.\tag2
\end{align}
$$
In (a) we use the fact that $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is symmetric, so is its own transpose; in (b) we see that everything except $\epsilon Y^T$ is non-stochastic. The expectation of $\epsilon Y^T$ is $$E(\epsilon Y^T)=E(\epsilon(\epsilon^T+\beta^TX^T)=E(\epsilon\epsilon^T)=:\Sigma=\sigma^2I,\tag3$$ so the RHS of (2) equals $\sigma^2\underbrace{(I-H)X}_{0}(X^TX)^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: Did you assume that $X$ is constant here in the equality $E(r) = (I - H)E[\epsilon]$?

Comment: Also, to show $E[r] = 0$, I don't think we actually need $E[\epsilon] = 0$ since, by construction, $E[r] = 0$ since $X \hat{\beta}$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the column space of $X$, and typically for OLS, the column space of $X$ includes a vector of ones.

Comment: @student010101 Yes, this derivation assumes $X$ is constant; otherwise you don't have a normal distribution for $r$ or $\hat\beta$.

Comment: @24n8 Actually we do require $E[\epsilon]=0$. We can conclude that $\sum r_i=0$ whenever the column space of $X$ includes a vector of ones, but this conclusion is not the same as the result $E[r]=0$.

Comment: +1. It is worth emphasizing that the goal is to prove that $E(r \hat{\beta}^T) = 0$, not $E(r^T \hat{\beta}) = 0$. The second expression would not make sense dimensionally. It is also not correct because to prove that two random vectors that are jointly Gaussian are independent, one needs to show that their covariance matrix is 0. The first expression gives their covariance matrix.

Comment: @grand_chat You showed that $r$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are uncorrelated. I know that zero correlation implies independence for jointly normal distribution, so I suppose that $r$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are jointly normal. But how can I prove this?

Comment: @ashpool You can use the fact that $r=(I-H)\epsilon$ is a linear transformation of $\epsilon$, and so is $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ (since $Y=X\beta +\epsilon$). So the vector $(r,\hat\beta)^T$ is a linear transformation of the jointly normal vector $\epsilon$.