# Show $\hat{\beta}$ and $s^2$ are independent?

Tags: statistics, regression

I have the model:

$y=X{\beta}+{\epsilon}$

I know $\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ and that it is an unbiased estimator of ${\beta}$ and that $s^2=\hat{\epsilon}'\hat{\epsilon}/(n-k)$ and is an unbiased estimator of the variance.

How do I show that $\hat{\beta}$ and $s^2$ are independent?

Comment: The two estimates are in orthogonal subspaces. I think you need to mention that that errors are iid normal. A similar, but simpler situation is that for iid normal data $X_i,$ we have $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are stochastically independent (even though $\bar X$ appears in the definition of $S^2.$

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I was thinking that I needed to do something to do with covariance?

Comment: Be careful with that. Zero covariance (or correlation) implies independence _only_ for normal random variables. Even if errors are are normal, that doesn't mean distributions of $\hat \beta$ and $s^2$ are normal. (Example: For uniform data, $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are _not_ independent.) OK if $\hat \beta$ and $s^2$ are functions of orthogonal sets of normal variates.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo ok but this question is a show that question which normally means there's some algebra to be done and then at the end out pops the answer? Is there any way that this could be done algebraically?

Comment: There are a few methods of proving independence, none of them magical. No context provided. Difficult to be helpful. Maybe start with simple linear regression. Write $\bar X$ and $S^2$ in terms of data. Look at ANOVA table. Why are "Regression" and "Error" on different rows? Why is DF(Total) = DF(Regression) + DF(Error)?

Comment: @BruceTrumbo the only other pieces of information in the question are that X is nxk of non-stochastic regressors satisying rank(X)=k, ${\beta}$ is a kx1 vector of unkown parameters and ${\epsilon}$~N(0,${\sigma}^2I_n)$ where ${\sigma}$ is unkown. The normal OLS estimators for ${\beta}$ and ${\sigma}$ apply

Comment: Please do what I suggested for simple linear regression. Then think about it. Please edit relevant info into statement of question. Please give us some idea about your probability background proving independence. For example, just for a univariate normal sample, do you know how to prove $\bar X$ and $S$ are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Since $s^2:=\hat\epsilon^T\hat\epsilon/(n-k)$ is a function of the residual vector $\hat\epsilon:=Y-X\hat\beta$, this result follows from [the independence of $\hat\beta$ and $Y-X\hat\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/980363/215011).

Comment: +1. Is there an intuitive way to see why $\hat{\beta}$ is independent of the residual vector, and is there anything deeper/useful that one can get from this observation?