# Independence of SSE with regression coefficients

Tags: statistical-inference, linear-regression

I'm studying a simple linear regression model $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i$ are normally distributed i.i.d., and the least square fitting $\hat{y}_i=b_0+b_1x_i$.
$$SSE=\sum_i(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2$$
Apparently SSE is independent of both $b_0$ and $b_1$. How can I prove this?
I found a proof that SSE and $b_0,b_1$ are uncorrelated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980363/if-y-x-beta-epsilon-prove-that-the-least-square-estimator-hat-beta-is-ind), but in order for this to imply independence they should be jointly normally distributed; how can I prove the joint normality?

Comment: The joint normality of $\mathbf{e}:= \mathbf{y}-\widehat{\mathbf{y}}=(I-H)\mathbf{y}$ and $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}=\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X^T\mathbf{y}$ follows from the fact that both are equal to "some matrix times $\mathbf{y}$" and $\mathbf{y}$ is joint normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to shows that the residual $Y-X\hat \beta$ is independent of $\hat \beta$ by relying on the joint normality of
$(Y-X\hat \beta,\hat \beta)$.

Note that $Y-X\hat \beta = (I-H)\epsilon$ and $\hat \beta = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top Y = \beta + (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top \epsilon$,
hence both $Y-X\hat \beta$ and $\hat \beta$ are affine transformations of $\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ has multivariate normal distribution, the joint distribution of $(Y-X\hat \beta,\hat \beta)$ is normal.